# to turn turtle 90 degrees

Tags: netlogo, turtle-graphics

The orientation (heading) of turtles must be set randomly when wandering but must be limited to a range of 40 degrees (20 to the left and 20 to the right) per step taken, the only exception to this is when avoiding other agents, in this instance a maximum turn of 90 degrees is permitted.

I am new to netlogo. I want these movements with my turtles.

```
to move-turtles
  ask turtles[
    if who = ticks[
      stop]
    let agent-ahead one-of turtles-on patch-ahead 1
    ifelse agent-ahead != nobody [
      
      ??????
      ][
       rt random 20
       lt random 20
     
      ]
      fd 0.2
  ]
```

Comment: Could you state your exact problem? Have you tried adding in `rt random 45`  in place of "?????"

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments you can just use `rt` and `lt` with `random 45` to achieve what you want.

```
to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks 
  
  crt 5 [set color red]
  
end 

to go
  ask turtles[
    if who = ticks[
      stop]
    fd 1 
    let agent-ahead one-of turtles-on patch-ahead 1
    ifelse agent-ahead != nobody [
      set color blue
      ifelse random 2 = 1 [rt random 45] [lt random 45]
      ][set color red
       rt random 20
       lt random 20
     
      ]
      fd 0.2
  ]
  tick
end
```